# Resizing multidimensional array once

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, console

I am making a board game where I have x and y positions on the board.

I am adding functionality where the user can pick the dimensions of the board, but there is one problem.

I need to access the board using a function, so I have declared the board outside of my Sub Main().

I have heard you can use ReDim, but have also seen this isn't best practice?

How do I resize the 2-dimensional array **inside** Sub Main() once the user has entered the board dimensions?

Or am I mistaken that ReDim is bad practice, when in fact it is good practice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ReDim should work for what youre asking, just be sure to be aware of values that you may lose if you resize to a smaller array.

You are correct to declare the array globally if you want to use it across functions. Another option would be to initialize in the Sub Main and pass it byRef to the supporting functions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement

Comment: Redim ArrayName will allways clear the values from the array. Redim Preserve ArrayName will keep the values. As far as the new dimensions allows that.